# Explicitly passing in props to access it for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element, react-props

I'm currently going through the React beginner tutorial and I'm having trouble understanding the section "Lifting State Up, Again"

This is the website:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

At a certain point, we have to transform the board component by doing this:

```
Delete the constructor in Board.
Replace this.state.squares[i] with this.props.squares[i] in Board’s renderSquare.
Replace this.handleClick(i) with this.props.onClick(i) in Board’s renderSquare.
```

However, if we delete the board constructor, how do we have access to this.props.squares[i] and this.props.onClick(i)? I thought we had to explicitly pass in props somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: The default constructor of a React component class assigns the props to `this.props`, so you can reference them in e.g. your `render()`-method using `this.props`. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: Yes, the parent component rendering `Board` will pass `squares` and `onClick` props. All react components have access to props, either in `this.props` for class-based components, or simply `props` for functional components (*provided the function is defined as `MyComponent = props => {...`*).